# Temporaily disable conent management

Tags: control-panel, ee5

Is anyone aware of a way (add-on or other) of temporaily suspending a member group from publishing content?

For example when perfoming dev tasks my process is normally somethig like this (simlified for brevity):

- Sync live database to local working copy (via SQL dump)
- Perform dev tasks
- Push workgin copy code to live server
- SQL dump of wokring copy database to live server

Oviously, any changes to the DB on the live server during this period would be overridden.

I know I can disable CMS access to a certain member group for a period of time, but this shows a rather bland Forbidden message - which can be quite shokcing to client. It would be nicer to let them login to the control panel and show them a friendly "content freeze" message or similar.

Any thoughts? How do you manage this situation when dealing with a site where the client has publising privilages?

Answer (score 0):

I just tell clients not to change anything between the hours I'm working on the site, and any changes made during that period will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this add-on:

https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cp-pad-lock

You'll need to update it to work with EE4/5, which is a pretty easy to accomplish. I've done it myself and even created a CP page where you can edit the message users receive when they try to log in.

However, I would never consider freezing content for simple dev work. And I certainly would never make database changes on a local copy and push it to your true source copy (production database). That scares me (and my clients).

Answer (score 0):

You can also revoke the channel posting rights for the member group temporarily